# knockout - Check all checkboxes when binding data through Json

Tags: knockout.js

I get data from backend in Json in the following format:

```
 Column 1 Column 2 Column 3 Column 4 
 Text     Text     Text     Text
```

My json object does not have a `selected` or `IsChecked` property and I want to add a check box column as the first column in my html table and whenever the checkbox in the header is clicked, all the other checkboxes shoudld be checked and if any checkbox in the `<td>` is unchecked then the header checkbox should be uncheckd. I have tried [this](http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/kXYuU/) fiddle, but the 
header checkbox is not working and checking any checkbox in the `<td>` is checking all other checkboxes. What could be the problem?

Comment: do you have an updated fiddle with your attempt?

Comment: For me looks like the fiddle is working fine

Comment: It looks like you are using Knockout version 1.2.1 in you fiddle.  The current version 3.1.0. Consider moving to a newer version if that is an option.

Comment: The fiddle doesn`t replicate your problem, update the fiddle.